# Apache Hive Add TIMESTAMP partition using alter table statement

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hiveql

i'm currently running `MSCK HIVE REPAIR SCHEMA.TABLENAME` for all my tables after data is loaded.

As the partitions are growing, this statement is taking much longer (some times more than 5 mins) for one table. I know it scans and parses through all partitions in s3 (where my data is) and then adds the latest partitions into hive metastore.

I want to replace **MSCK REPAIR** with **ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION** statement. **MSCK REPAIR** works perfectly fine with adding latest partitions, however i'm facing problem with **TIMESTAMP** value in the partition when using **ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION**.

I have a table with four partitions `(part_dt STRING, part_src STRING, part_src_file STRING, part_ldts TIMESTAMP)`.

After running **MSCK REPAIR, the SHOW PARTITIONS command gives me below output

```
hive> show partitions hub_cont;
OK
part_dt=20181016/part_src=asfs/part_src_file=kjui/part_ldts=2019-05-02 06%3A30%3A39
```

But, when i drop the above partition from metastore, and recreate it using ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION

```
hive> alter table hub_cont add partition(part_dt='20181016',part_src='asfs',part_src_file='kjui',part_ldts='2019-05-02 06:30:39');
OK
Time taken: 1.595 seconds
hive> show partitions hub_cont;
OK
part_dt=20181016/part_src=asfs/part_src_file=kjui/part_ldts=2019-05-02 06%3A30%3A39.0
Time taken: 0.128 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

It is adding **.0** at the end of timestamp value. When i query the table for this partition, it is giving me 0 records.

Is there way to add parition that has timestamp value without getting this zero added at the end. I'm unable to figure out how MSCK REPAIR is handling this case that is ALTER TABLE statement not able to.

Answer (score 0):

The same should happen if you insert dynamic partitions, it will create new partitions with  .0 because default timestamp string representation format includes milliseconds part, `REPAIR TABLE` finds new folders and adds partition to the metastore and also works correct because timestamp string without milliseconds is quite compatible with the timestamp...

The solution is to use `STRING` instead of `TIMESTAMP` and remove milliseconds explicitly.

But first of all double-check that you have really millions of rows in single partition and really need timestamp grain partition, not DATE and this partition column is really significant (for example if it is functionally dependent on another partition column part_src_file, you can completely get rid of it). Too many partitions will cause performance degradation.